# Automatically fadeOut Div when its visible

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a Div which will appear when there is a session, else it will remain hidden.

What I want is to Automatically and Slowly fadeout that Div after some seconds when it becomes visible.

**Here is my Code and what I have tried so far:**

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){ ?>
   <div class="message">
    <?php echo $_SESSION['message']; ?>
   </div>
<?php unset($_SESSION['message']); } ?>
```

**The Jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if( $('.message').is(':visible') ) {

  $(".message").fadeOut(1000);

}
</script>
```

The problem I am facing is that DIV appears but it doesn't Fadeout or disappear automatically. 
**Plus there are no Errors in Console.**

Comment: Is the javascript above or below the php? Are you trying to access the element before it exists?

Comment: First, just write `$(".message").fadeOut(1000);` on pageload and refresh and check whether div fades-out or not. If div fades this way, means the problem is in "is" condition otherwise something else.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a timeout, or an interval. Or even to run a check to see if the element exists or is visible.

You do need to run this code when your document is ready though or at the very least, after the `.message` element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.message').delay(5000).fadeOut(300);
});
```

If there is no `.message` element, it won't have any negative effects.

Comment: Amen I don't understand how someone can suggest polling with a timeout as a legitimate answer

Comment: Alternatively, just make sure your jquery script runs after the div is added to the HTML

Comment: Really? The first code example of the docs uses this exact method as an example: `$( "#foo" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 800 ).fadeIn( 400 );`. `.delay()` will work with any method that's involved in the effects queue, but it can also be used for custom queues.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your code is not working as it is executing only once when the DOM is ready. You need to check value in a regular interval basis. So here you need to do something like this

You can also do this by setTimeout function

```
setTimeout(function(){
    if( $('.message').is(':visible') ) 
      $(".message").fadeOut(1000);
},100);
```

Or as I said above to execute the code you have to put it in $(document).ready function (when the DOM is ready)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 if( $('.message').is(':visible') ) 
    $(".message").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Comment: A polling interval is such a hack. OP just needs to make sure the jquery call is made after the div is loaded, or in the onready event

Comment: Yes, the clearInterval is required when the div will hide. OP needs to update code according to his requirement, I just put some views on it(check the updated answer).

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. There is no need for a set interval as you have shown.  Please remove it from your answer and I'll remove my down vote.